# SQLParameterCollection AddWithValue and Add does not escape wildcard symbols

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am currently building an API that allows a user to search for a database object using the name. The stored Procedure runs this query as the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [GetMyDatabaseObjectByName] 
    @name varchar(255)
as
begin
select mdo.Name,
       mdo.ID
      from MyDatabaseObject mdo
      where mdo.Name like '%' + @name + '%'
end
```

I am calling this query from my C# application as follows:

```
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
```

This is all great and dandy however if the user passes in a **'%'** symbol as my QA engineer so gracefully did, the stored procedure will return every element in the database because it interprets it as the following:

```
 select mdo.Name,
        mdo.ID
      from MyDatabaseObject mdo
      where mdo.Name like '%' + '%' + '%'
```

I have tried using

```
dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;
```

But I am getting the same result. According to the documentation I thought that **Add** or **AddWithValue** would escape the string automatically in order to avoid this.

Questions:

Is there any built in solution in the **System.Data.SqlClient** that will escape any symbols passed in?

What would be the preferred approach here, using regex at the client level to avoid it passing in any funky characters?

Comment: Not sure what you want it to be escaped to. An empty string? It would still do the same thing. Meanwhile you might want to take a peek at this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @SeanLange Precisely, if I allow a % to go through it will break the application since there are too many elements in the database. I need to avoid this from happening.

Comment: @Lostaunaum This is a problem because you've moved the bad practice of building queries via string concatenation from the C# side to the stored procedure side. It's the exact same problem. Don't do it.

Comment: Then don't allow it from the front end.

Comment: Whereas, if they pass just the string `e` they'll only get *most* of the rows from the table? (Assuming english letter distributions in text). Where do you try to stop the madness? `e` isn't usually considered a special character and yet it has many of the same drawbacks as allowing `%`.

Comment: @DanielMann moving this to a procedure isn't going to solve that. They are adding leading and trailing wildcards to the user input. And it is properly parameterized.

Comment: @SeanLange Unless I'm missing something, it **already is** a stored procedure. My understanding is that he's taking user input, passing it into a stored procedure, then building a SQL query in the stored procedure containing the user input, and running that query. It's still doing string concatenation, just in a different place.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes there is a stored procedure I will add it to the question

Comment: @DanielMann apparently it is a procedure. But how do you do a query with like that receives a parameter without string concatenation?

Comment: there is no need to pass a %, an empty search string would do the same. the server is doing exactly what you tell it to do. cannot be solved by escaping, define your goal first, like requiring a minimum number of characters in the search string. underscores are also wildcards (single-character wildcards, that is) in a `LIKE` expression. And letter groups in square brackets as well. at least the parameter approach is not a sql injection vulnerability here.

Comment: If there is some logical limit to the application maybe you should consider using TOP or paging the results.

Comment: > `"According to the documentation I thought that Add or AddWithValue would escape the string automatically in order to avoid this."` That's not how it works at all. If you're trying to escape problem characters, you've already lost. Query parameters work but _isolating_ or _quarantining_ the **entire** parameter value from the rest of the command, regardless of what special characters it may or may not contain. Nothing is escaped at all, and this is fine because the quarantine approach is superior: data is data, code is code, and never the twain shall meet.

Comment: [continued] With regards to the wild card issue here. This is the expected behavior, and in fact lots of software relies on this working as it is. If you don't want wild cards, you'll need to exclude them on the front end via the C# code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you we are going to manually escape problematic characters at the service level:
            return input
                    .Replace("[", "\\[")
                    .Replace("]", "\\]")
                    .Replace("\\", "[\\]")
                    .Replace("%", "[%]")
                    .Replace("_", "[_]");
I can count your answer as valid.

Comment: ability to include wildcards in the input is a feature not a bug. it has nothing to do with string concatenation. you would see the same if you removed the string concatenation and just used `mdo.Name like @name` and passed a parameter containing wild cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add** and **AddWithValue** will not automatically escape any symbols, in order to clean or escape symbols that may be passed in by your user you need to implement something like this

```
name = EscapeForLike(name)
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name); 

public static string EscapeForLike(string input)
{
    return input
        .Replace("[", "\\[")
        .Replace("]", "\\]")
        .Replace("\\", "[\\]")
        .Replace("%", "[%]")
        .Replace("_", "[_]");
}
```

Comment: simpler to just use `CHARINDEX` if you dont want user supplied wildcards and are appending leading and trailing wildcards anyway